# Using support library

Tags: android, android-support-library

Is there any tutorial available on the net about using support library? I am little confused because in my activity I imported all the widgets from a support library and I still get markers that say I need api 11. Do I have to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity to use it?

EDIT:

My problem was that I extended Activity instead of FragmentActivity. This problem is mentioned here: [getLoaderManager().initLoader() doesn't accept 'this' as argument though the class (ListFragment) implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155753/getloadermanager-initloader-doesnt-accept-this-as-argument-though-the-cla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html) is a good explanation on how to use the support library.

Regarding `FragmentActivity`, you have to use it if you are trying to use a `Fragment` in an `Activity`.

Also be careful to import the proper classes. An example for a Fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```